# array is returning repetitive Json data

Tags: php, json, mysqli

It's returning something like this:

```
[
      {
        "0": "1",
        "1": "Udon House",
        "2": "food",
        "3": "31.5076701",
        "4": "74.3544522",
        "5": "a trip to the landa.",
        "6": "images/udonHouse.jpg",
        "place_id": "1",
        "place_name": "Udon House",
        "category": "food",
        "lat": "31.5076701",
        "lon": "74.3544522",
        "description": "a trip to the landa.",
        "db_image": "images/udonHouse.jpg"
      },
      {
        "0": "5",
        "1": "Lahore Meuseum",
        "2": "attractions",
        "3": "31.5681556",
        "4": "74.3061492",
        "5": "want to discover histroy?",
        "6": "images/badshahi.jpg",
        "place_id": "5",
        "place_name": "Lahore Meuseum",
        "category": "attractions",
        "lat": "31.5681556",
        "lon": "74.3061492",
        "description": "want to discover histroy?",
        "db_image": "images/badshahi.jpg"
      }
    ]
```

this is my php code:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="tourist"; // Database name 
    $con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

if($con){

    mysqli_set_charset($con ,'utf8');

    $user_id  = $_POST['user_id'];

    $qry =

    ("SELECT p.*
FROM
  places p INNER JOIN
  favorites f ON p.place_id = f.place_id INNER JOIN
  user u ON u.id = f.user_id
WHERE
   u.id = $user_id");

    $query=mysqli_query($con ,$qry);        

    if (!$query) {
                $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
                $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $qry;
                die($message);
    }

    $return_arr = array();


    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


            header('Content-Type: application/json');

            array_push($return_arr,$r);
        }
        echo json_encode($return_arr);
    }
    }

?>
```

Why is it returning the rows two times in an object ?I only want the data with names not with the numberings what am I doing wrong here?
Any suggestions or alternate solutions please?

Comment: by default the `mysqli_fetch_array` returns the results in both numeric and an associative array, you can use the 2nd parameter to set which one you want which would be `mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: because you are fetching array, i dont use mysqli but i think there is something like mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)this will keep the keys for your array instead of indexs which you dont need

Comment: _I know I am wasting my breath but if you were to_ **[RT?M](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)** you could have worked that out all on your own

Comment: @HatemAhmed thank you :)

Comment: @cmorrissey  got it! thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By *default*, the `mysqli_fetch_array` function, uses `MYSQLI_BOTH` as its "result type".

You need to set the 2nd parameter to `MYSQLI_ASSOC` to have it only return the key names.

```
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    array_push($return_arr,$r);
}
```

P.S. `header('Content-Type: application/json');` only needs to be called *once*, so take it out of the `while` loop.